# Обращение к Майе

Tags: обращение

Можно к Майе обратиться *"Май"?*

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, да.

Вообще в русском языке звательный падеж исчез, однако некоторые остатки его сохраняются.

В частности:

> В то же время, иногда под «современным звательным падежом» (или «новозвательным») понимаются словоформы с нулевым окончанием существительных первого склонения, как «Миш», «Лен», «Тань», «Марин», «Танюш», «Ванюш», «бабуль», «мам», «пап» и т. п., то есть совпадающие по форме со склонением множественного числа родительного падежа. Статус данной формы слова пока остаётся предметом споров учёных: часть склоняется к выделению подобной формы в отдельную грамматическую категорию, часть же выступает против [[Википедия]](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6).

*«Майя»* — это первое склонение. С нулевым окончанием будет как раз *«Май»* и это совпадает по форме со склонением множественного числа родительного падежа.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Артём Луговой Если Вам ответ подходит, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый. А то, я не пойму, Вы мне спасибо сказали, что приятно, но ответ, как принятый не отметили. Почему?

Comment: Что это вы вдруг стали лишние запятые ставить?) Я вам плюсик поставил, а принимать пока не хочу — хочу ещё ответов. А то, если приму, тогда тем более никто отвечать не станет.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Ясно. Да, с запятыми напутал.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Ещё у меня сложилось мнение, что вы не приняли данный мой ответ, который является исчерпывающим, из солидарности с некоторыми пользователями, которые больше озабочены своими репутационными балами, питающими их эго, чем установлением истины, и обиделись на меня за непринятие своих ответов. Может вы считаете, что я несправедливо как-то с вами лично поступил? Я такого не помню. Поясните свою позицию.

Comment: Да не обижался я, просто хочу ответов ещё от тех, чьё мнение для меня важно. Чем больше, тем лучше, лишь бы не заумными были ответы. И после этого мог бы принять и ваш, но этого я заранее не знаю. Если я приму ответ, другие не захотят отвечать на него, а одного ответа мне мало. Вы бы тоже могли за вопрос проголосовать.

Comment: @Артём Луговой  Я давно проголосовал, это кто-то поставил минус вашему вопросу, и поэтому 0. Там один голос мой +1 и чей-то -1.

Comment: О, спасибо! Так это ваш плюсик? Очень приятно! Да, видел, что кто-то минусовал, почти уверен, что это Jim Korbett, ответ которого удалили.

Comment: Интересно мнение других, а также мне не хватает примеров такого употребления (именно с Майей).

Comment: @Артём Луговой Это не частое имя. А если искать примеры, то, наверное, будет выходить много ответов с месяцем маем. А какие есть ещё варианты? Как ещё можно сказать? Почему у вас нет уверенности? Я не настаиваю на принятии моего ответа, просто не пойму в чём сомнение.

Comment: Нашёл-таки примеры у одного автора! [Вот](http://novlit.ru/rair/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B/%D0%B0-%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C/i-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/).

Comment: Круто! Как вам это удалось? «Май, пива хочешь?» — тут чёткое совпадение, и по смыслу звательный падеж. Но вот тут «Конечно, Май!» не понятное мне использование, тут не должен быть звательный падеж, это выражение согласия, должно быть «Конечно, Майя!». «Май» — это если звать, например, можно сказать: «Май, помоги мне, пожалуйста».

Comment: Нет, звательный может быть при любом обращении. Я загуглил (без знаков препинания) фразу "это ты, Май". :) Имел в виду вопросительную, но там оказалась утвердительная, где имя прерывало высказывание.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Почитал про звательный падеж. Да, действительно, звательный падеж используется при любом обращение. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6): «используемая для идентификации объекта, к которому ведётся обращение». Так что подходит в «Конечно, Май!». Хорошо, что у вас получилось найти пример использования.